# Difference in naming between consulting and consultants

Tags: meaning, grammar, vocabulary

I have a domain research for a company and since English is not my first language I was wondering about the difference between e.g.

*Boston Consulting* and *Boston Consultants*

My guess is that the first one refers to the company as a whole and the second refers to the people of the company.

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 3):

You should not assume that either refers to a Company (which is a legal structure) since either term could also be used for a partnership or another corporate structure.

You are correct in inferring that using *Boston Consulting* tends to focus attention on the entity as a whole and their shared capabilities while *Boston Consultants* emphasises the individuals that make up the group and their particular expertise.

The choice is probably more concerned with "branding" or image than with governance. There is no reason that one man operating out of his garage could not register and use the name Boston Consulting to disguise the fact that he is the only consultant available (and perhaps the receptionist as well.)